# MIP Formulation Slow Performance

Tags: cplex, mixed-integer-programming, docplex

I am working on a model which is MIP. The model solves very quickly generally, but if I am trying to add IF- THEN constraint to the model the solve time exponentially increases to a point where its not able to get a feasible solution within 2000s.  I have also tried indicator constraints but without any luck. Is there alternative to IF- THEN constraint which solves faster? or should I reduce the horizon of my problem to get a solve? or are there any CPLEX parameters which performs better with IF- THEN constraints? Any ideas are welcomed

Answer (score 0):

you could have a look at the technote

Difference between using indicator constraints and a big-M formulation

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/397209

And if your model is about scheduling you could have a look at

https://www.slideshare.net/PhilippeLaborie/planningscheduling-with-cp-optimizer

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Cplex through DOcplex or OPL?
Are you experiencing slow performance in model *building* or in model *solve*?

To investigate slow performance in solve, could you try reduce the problem as much as possible and generate a LP or SAV file? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Philippe, I am using docplex and seeing slowness during model solving. I tried to divide my model for multiple horizons and used output of one horizon as input of other which gave me faster solve

Answer (score 0):

DOcplex's if-then construct allocates *two* internal constraints: one equivalence constraint to define the `if_ct` status variable, and one indicator constraint to link this status variable to the `then_ct`. At the end of the day, two indicator constraints are generated.

If the condition consists in one boolean variable tested against 0 or 1, this might be simplified to *one* indicator constraint (actually, this simplification will be done in Docplex's next version). For example, this code allocates one indicator constraint

```
 m.add_indicator_constraint(b, y>=3)
```

but this one allocates two:

```
m.if_then(b==1, y>=3)
```

which is not really necessary. However, if the condition constraint is not a simple binary variable test, the `if-then` construct is the way to go.

If a large number of if-then constructs are used, this might explain the solve performance issue? It would help to have the numbers as printed by `Model.print_information` to see how large your model really is.